# How to create a pull request from reverted Git commit?

Tags: git, github

I have a master branch to which I pushed a commit by mistake. I should have pushed it to a feature branch. So, I have reverted that commit from the master branch, and pushed a revert:

```
git revert <commit-hash>
git push
```

Then I have created a new feature branch where I would like to use that commit that I have pushed by mistake to the master branch.
I have cherry picked the commit to that branch:

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

When I do `git status`, I get:

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Since I would like to make a pull request from that branch, I can't make it without having a commit.
How can I make it so that the reverted commit is displayed as a new commit on a feature branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a cherry pick, the working tree *is* clean, so git status is correct. The cherry pick you just made *is* the commit you want. So don't worry, be happy. Push your lovely new branch!

Answer (score 0):

You can `git revert` the reverted commit.  A revert creates a new commit that cancels out the reverted commit, and if you revert a revert commit it restores the changes.

Cherry pick may be behaving unexpectedly as the history still contains the commit you're cherry-picking.  It sees that commit is already in your branch's history.

Edit: scratch that.  If your concern is just that `git status` is clean then [matt's answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70960090/60724).  Cherry pick has succeeded and committed the change to your branch (it effectively did the `git commit` for you--bringing along the changes, message, and other commit metadata).

If you review `git log` you should see the cherry-picked commit.  To *checkout* the changes from an old commit you could do `git checkout SHA_HASH some_file.txt`, which would then show it as an untracked change in your working copy.